# Higher dimensional Apollonius problem with $n+1$ spheres forming a ring

Tags: geometry

Assume that we have $n-1$-spheres $S_{i}$ for $i=1,...,n+1$ such that $S_{i}$ and $S_{i+1}$ are tangent for all $i$ and $S_{n+1}$ is tangent to $S_1$. 
What is the condition on the radius of the spheres to deduce that there exists at least two spheres tangent to all of $S_i$'s.